# Discord command doesn't work if user has changed their nickname

Tags: javascript, discord.js, mention

My if statement won't work if the user has changed their nickname in the guild.

Does anyone know how can I get around this?

```
if (message.content.includes(message.mentions.users.first())) {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (results.afk === 1) {
        message.channel.send(`${user} is AFK - ${results.reason} (${moment(results.afktime).fromNow()})`);
    }
}
```

`results.afk` is from an mySQL key object. The above works if the user has not changed his nickname in discord.

I created a temp/test function:

```
console.log(message.mentions.users)

        if (message.content.includes(message.mentions.users.first())){
            console.log("Has mention")
        }
```

- If I mention a user in discord that **has not** changed his username, I get the collection data from `console.log(message.mentions.users)` and `"Has mention"`.
- If I mention a user in discord that **has** changed his username I only get the collection data from `console.log(message.mentions.users)`.

The issue lies with `(message.content.includes(message.mentions.users.first()))`. That is not detecting a mention in the message if the user changes his nickname. I need a way to pass the if function if there is a **user mention** (not @everyone, @here #channelname).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (message.isMentioned(message.mentions.users.first()))` solved it for me.

Comment: it seems as if `message.content` refers to the `user.nickname`, while `message.mentions` also knows the `user.id`